# SWT Combo Read Only mode background color

Tags: java, swt

I'd like to have a read-only combo dropdown in my Eclipse RCP application but when I set the Read Only flag the background always stays gray. This is my code:

```
    Combo combo = new Combo(fCompositeLogin_1, SWT.READ_ONLY);
    combo.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    combo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 2, 1));
    for(String i : items) {
        combo.add(i);
    }
    combo.select(0);
```

I'd like to have it with a white background, how can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like the native control sets this color and SWT does not have anything to change it. The `CCombo` control does set the drop down list color from `setBackground`

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by wrapping the Combo inside a white composite and setting the composite's inherit mode to force.

```
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
composite.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
composite.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
comboCombo = new Combo(composite, SWT.READ_ONLY);
```

Comment: The suggested solution does not work on Windows. See here for a possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340605/set-color-for-swt-combo/41341967#41341967