# Set color for SWT Combo

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to turn color of my readonly combo to white as a non-readonly combo
[image]

My code for the readonly Combo

```
Combo myCombo = new Combo(sessionProperties, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY, "");
```

*I also try to set background and foreground, but it not this thing.*
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [background color is a hint](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FControl.html&anchor=setBackground(org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color)). On some platforms, some controls cannot change their background color.

The SWT `CCombo` is a custom control that emulates the behavior of a combo box by using a text input field, a button, and a list.

Setting the background to white changes the text and list background color only. Not sure if that is what you were looking for.

[image]

[image]

If you think it's worth the effort you can still use the `CCombo` widget as a template to build your own all-white combo box.

Comment: I have some issues using CCombo in edit mode. Is it good idea to use CCombo in read only mode to display background color correctly and to use standard combo box in user input mode